# BluetoothLowEnergy UART Service

Tags: python, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, gatt

Im using the Adafruit_Python_BluefruitLE library to connect to my Arduino 101,
in the example code they show how to connect to some UART peripheral
The library defines some uuids for the service/characteristics:

```
UART_SERVICE_UUID = uuid.UUID('6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E')
TX_CHAR_UUID      = uuid.UUID('6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E')
RX_CHAR_UUID      = uuid.UUID('6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E')
```

Then it searches for devices matching those uuids:

```
device.discover([UART_SERVICE_UUID], [TX_CHAR_UUID, RX_CHAR_UUID])

# Find the UART service and its characteristics.
uart = device.find_service(UART_SERVICE_UUID)
rx = uart.find_characteristic(RX_CHAR_UUID)
tx = uart.find_characteristic(TX_CHAR_UUID)
```

I tried copying these uuids into my Arduino code and mirroring the device setup but that didnt work. So how do I have to set up the Arduino code so it can communicate with the library?